# Как передать параметр в конструктор класса из модуля в Dagger 2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger2, dagger

Как передать параметр в конструктор класса из модуля в  Dagger 2?

Определяю модуль GameModule: [image: GameModule]

Определяю компопнент GameComponent: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Инициализирую компонент: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда пытаюсь добавить снова параметр, то студия уже не видит этого метода и метода build() : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так делаю подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: а за чем эти методы в компоненте с болтунами и старками ?

Answer (score 0):

В Dagger2 большую роль играют возвращаемые типы

И в Builder'е компонента нужно указать этот же тип Builder'а как возвращаемый тип, чтобы дальше можно было вызывать на него методы